# Accessing java list of a user defined class type in javascript

Tags: javascript, java

How to access list of a class say A in java script?

```
Class A {
int a;
int b;
}

Class B{
List<A> listA = SomeListOfAType;
}

myjs.js
i want to access this list. i can have this like 
var list= "#{dataCaptureBean.listA}"; //provided getter of list
```

but when i do list[i] it returns letter by letter rather than object by object, how to acieve this ?

Comment: access it like list.a and list.b

Comment: What do you mean by *letter by letter* ?

Comment: letter by letter means if my list contains listA[0]->a=1,b=2 and listA[1]->a=3,b=4 (in java lists)
(list iteration in javascript) listA[0]='a', listA[1]='1' list[1]='b'

Answer (score 0):

i gues you use spring.

```
public @ResponseBody B method(..){
  B b = new B();
  ..
  return b;
}

success: funciton(response){
  if(response){
    var list = response.listA;
    for(var i = 0; < list.length; ++i){
      console.log(list[i].a + list[i].b);
    }
  }
}
```